# C# android xamarin bluetooth new devices

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I'm new with Xamarin Android and I created an APP. It is working fine with paired devices, however, when I try to search for new devices (unpaired) this does not work.

```
namespace eCommer
{
    [Activity(Label = "Control", MainLauncher = true)]

    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {

        private ListView listView;
        static List<string> bluetoothlist = new List<string>();
        DeviceDiscoveredReceiver receiver;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            //revisamos si el dispositivo tiene bluetooth
            if (adapter == null)
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alert.SetTitle("no soportado");
                alert.SetMessage("Su dispositivo no soporta bluetooth");
                alert.SetPositiveButton("salir", (senderAlert, e) =>
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "salir", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    Finish();
                    return;
                });
            }
            //revisamos si el bluetooth esta activado
            if (!adapter.IsEnabled)
            {
                Intent enableBT = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ActionRequestEnable);
                StartActivityForResult(enableBT, 1);
                Finish();
                return;
            }

            //ingresamos los componentes
            listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
            if (adapter.IsDiscovering)
            {
                adapter.CancelDiscovery();
                Finish();
                return;
            }
            else 
            {
                adapter.StartDiscovery();
            }

            receiver = new DeviceDiscoveredReceiver(this);
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ActionFound);
            RegisterReceiver(receiver, filter);
            filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ActionDiscoveryFinished);

            //listamos los bluetooth emparejados
            var lista_dispositivos = adapter.BondedDevices;
            if(lista_dispositivos.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach(var dispositivos_bluetooth in lista_dispositivos)
                {
                    bluetoothlist.Add(dispositivos_bluetooth.Name + " " + dispositivos_bluetooth.Address);
                }
                ArrayAdapter<string> arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, bluetoothlist);
                listView.Adapter = arrayadapter;
            }
        }

        //esta clase busca y agrega los dispositivos encontrados
        class DeviceDiscoveredReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
        {
            Activity mainActivity;
            public DeviceDiscoveredReceiver(Activity activity)
            {
                this.mainActivity = activity;
            }

            public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                string action = intent.Action;
                if (BluetoothDevice.ActionFound.Equals(action))
                {
                    BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice)intent.GetParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraDevice);
                    bluetoothlist.Add(device.Name);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have read almost the same pages more than ones but everything looks to be fine. Can someone see something wrong in this code? I already added permission to the `manifest.xml` page.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that your app is still holding onto the previously paired device, even though you may have unpaired the device in the OS. Try making sure the app has stopped completely after you unpaired the BT device (force stop the app in the OS) and see if it will discover again.

Comment: hi, thanks for respond... I delete the pairing part and unpaired all devices, and I did not work.... is not finding anything...... how can I see if we are accessing the discoverying class?